# Auto Boot after Power Failure - Laptop

Tags: boot, laptop, power-management, battery

I'm using a laptop with lubunut on it for a project I'm working on in a remote location. I chose a laptop because of the batter already attached and the frequent power outages. Most power outages are only for an hour or so, which the laptop will be fine on. But occasionally there are power outages that can last an entire day.

I would like the laptop to be able to boot automatically when it has AC power attached (such as if the battery completely died). Unfortunately, it's a cheap laptop Toshiba NB 200 and the Pheonix Bios does not have any settings for Boot After Power Failure. I could not find a BIOS update, but it seems silly that a laptop bios would be built in with this feature.

So, my question is, "Does this have to be a bios setting or is there some software for Ubunutu that would handle this?" Such as: "If the system shuts down, automatically boot the computer at 6:00am the next day."

The other thought I had was to hook some wires up to the power button switch and use a relay to "push" the button when it has AC power.

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

edit `/etc/grub.d/00_header` to resemble:

```
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=0     # <----edit this integer so that it is 0 [zero]
else
  set timeout=3
fi
```

the default for `set timeout` is `-1` which of course is "wait forever".

Comment: Its working great way with my system. perfect solution